# UnAnswered questions have answers

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I have selected the unanswered tag's and seeing unanswered questions,

But when I am click the last page in paging , there can see answered questions in unanswered tag.

Is it bug? or correct? [image]

Comment: If you select unanswer tab and then no-answer's tab then you get proper result. see http://i.stack.imgur.com/FUAFN.png

Comment: In short: zero scored non accepted answer is not considered a real answer in Stack Exchange standards.